# Get a list of database users and his/her permission right from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a report which will show database users and his/her permission on SQL Server. Below is the query that will do the job.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT  
[UserName] = CASE princ.[type] 
                WHEN 'S' THEN princ.[name]
                WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
             END,
[UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
                WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
             END,  
[DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],       
[Role] = null,      
[PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
[PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
[ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],       
[ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
[ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
--database user
sys.database_principals princ  
LEFT JOIN
--Login accounts
sys.login_token ulogin on princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
--Permissions
sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
--Table columns
sys.columns col ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE 
princ.[type] in ('S','U')
 UNION
--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
 SELECT  
[UserName] = CASE memberprinc.[type] 
                WHEN 'S' THEN memberprinc.[name]
                WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
             END,
[UserType] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
             END, 
[DatabaseUserName] = memberprinc.[name],   
[Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
[PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
[PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
[ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],   
[ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
[ColumnName] = col.[name]
 FROM    
--Role/member associations
sys.database_role_members members
 JOIN
--Roles
sys.database_principals roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
 JOIN
--Role members (database users)
sys.database_principals memberprinc ON memberprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
 LEFT JOIN
--Login accounts
sys.login_token ulogin on memberprinc.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
 LEFT JOIN        
--Permissions
sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
 LEFT JOIN
--Table columns
sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
 LEFT JOIN
sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
 )
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

The problem of this query is I need to manually run this statement by databases, if I have 10 databases on SQL Server then I need to run 10 times to get report from different databases.

Now I thinking to automate this job, what I'm think is to get list of databases from sql server by below sql statement.

```
SELECT name
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

and pass these results to store procedures. But I'm stuck at there, any help are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways how you can achieve this.

**1) EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command** 
You can use such command to run your query on each database on your server. Example [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/).

**2) Cursor** 
You can also use `Cursor`, example [here](http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/t-sql-a-simple-example-using-a-cursor/).

**3) Dynamic SQL** 
Last option is IMO rewriting your query into `Dynamic SQL`. Example [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/).

It all depends how exactly this should work, what should be the result - one table with stored results or just see the results in SSMS.

Comment: Thanks  for your suggestion, I able to get reports by using a cursor + dynamic SQL.